# Active Record efficient querying on multiple different tables

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, performance, activerecord

Let me give a summary of what I've been attempting to do and the efficiency issues I've been running into:

Essentially I want my users to be able to select parameters to filter data from my database, then I want to pass relevant data which passes those filters from the controller.

However, these filters query on data from multiple different tables (that is, about 5-6 different tables), some of which are quite large (as in 100k+ rows). These tables are all related to what I want to show, e.g. Here is a bond that meets so and so criteria, which is issued by so and so issuer, which must meet these criteria, and so on.

From an end result, I only really need about 100 rows after querying based on the parameters given by the user, but it feels like I need to look at everything in every table because I dont know how strict the filters will be beforehand. e.g. With a starting universe of 100k sets of data, passing filter f1,f2 of Table 1 might leave 90k, but after passing through filter f3 of table 2, f4,f5,f6 of table 3, and so ..., we might end up with 100 or less sets of data that pass these parameters because the last filters checked might be quite strict.

How can I go about querying through these multiple different tables efficiently?

Doing a join between them seems like it'd yield some time complexity of |T_1||T_2||T_3||T_4||T_5||T_6| where T_i is the "size" of table i.

On the other hand, just looking through the other tables based off the ids of the ones that pass the previous filter (as in, id 5,7,8 pass filters in T_1, which of those ids then pass filters in T_2, then which of those pass filters in T_3 and so on) looks like it might(?) have time complexity of |T_1| + |T_2| + ... + |T_6|.

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails, so im not entirely sure all of the tools at my disposal that could help with optimizing this, but at the same time I'm not entirely sure how to best approach this algorithmically.

Comment: Can't you translate all the filters to a single query? This would surely be the most efficient way to do this, because databases are optimized for it.

Comment: The Ransack gem would most likely help you with this, by constructing a single query (as @maraca suggests) based on params. Pushing this to the database as a single query is almost certainly going to give you the best performance and most simple code.